# How to get elements of JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I have a `JSONObject` that contains some `JSONObjects` as follows:

```
"statistics": {
    "John": {
      "Age": "22",
      "status": "married"
    },
    "Ross": {
      "Age": "34",
      "status": "divorced"
    }
 }
```

Now all I know is the object name(statistics), and **don't know** it's **elements number** or it's **elements names** , So, is there's a way to parse that Object so that I can get it's elements and deal with it (ie. John, Ross) ?

Comment: try http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: What JSON library are you using? There is not (yet) a standard JSON API for Java.

Comment: it's org.json, but I didn't mention it to make the question open for people so that If there's only a specific library that can do that I will use it as I don't mind changing org.json in that case

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourdata);
String statistics = json.getString("statistics");
JSONObject name1 = json.getJSONObject("John");
String ageJohn = name1.getString("Age");
```

For getting those items in a dynamic way:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourdata);
String statistics = json.getString("statistics");

for (Iterator key=json.keys();key.hasNext();) {
    JSONObject name = json.get(key.next());
    //now name contains the firstname, and so on... 
}
```

Comment: well, that works and gives me the contained Objects each, but how to get the Names of these objects?

Comment: Yes. As displayed in the example.   String key = key.next(); JSONObject name = json.get(key);    Log.d("data", "key="+key+ " and value="+json.toString());

Comment: i got error: `Error:(65, 48) java: incompatible type: java.lang.Object cannot be casted to java.lang.String`

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify which library you intend to use to represent the JSON object. Usually there are methods to enumerate the properties of the object. For example:

```
org.json.JSONObject.keys()
```

returns an iterator of the String names in the object.